# asp.net active directory logging in

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, asp.net-membership

i would like to be able to login on a webpage using a valid active directory username and password.

user name and password are entered in textboxes. if they are correct then i would like to redirect to another page.

how can this be coded.

in a second task

after some code is performed, log in as an administrator using code and unlock the account.

i have heard that this is called impersonation.

how can i perform the above??

i'm using visual web developer 2008 and vb.net

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at implementing the [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx). Here's a good [walk through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx) on how to implement it.